# Firefox Add-ons: "x" as Add-on name?

Tags: firefox

[image]

Is this normal? Why is the Add-on named "x"? - not just this one, any add-on that I want to install named "x"..

Why?

p.s.: from the https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/ site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like that URL points to Adblock Plus (as does the author's name). My guess is that something was accidentally pushed to release with a placeholder for the version / name. I tend to use "x", and various combinations of "foo" and "bar".

Unfortunately, your question doesn't give me anything else to go on and is too point-in-time to really get anything useful.